# Свежие новости

Tags: грамотная-речь

Часто можно услышать словосочетание "свежие новости". Но ведь, если это новости, то они уже свежие, а если несвежие, то это не новости.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Новости в значении "информация". А информация может быть свежей, новой.

Comment: У "новости" нет значения "информация". Только "недавно полученная информация". Т.е. свежая. Вопрос о тавтологичности вполне уместнен. Другое дело, что новости вполне может быть и первой, и второй свежести. См. ответ _**inn'ы c подеркиваниями**_

Answer (score 4):

А разве нельзя сказать *устаревшая новость*, *вчерашняя новость*, *утренняя* или *вечерняя*? Ничего не имею против *свежих* или *последних* новостей. Разве что нельзя никак сказать *новые новости*.

Comment: Ещё раз пожалел, что движок не позволяет обратиться к вам по нику.

Comment: Ага, действительно получается просто @__inna__, без подчеркиваний. То ли ник не очень удачный, то ли недоработка программистов...

Comment: Обратитесь в "Мета" (гиперссылка внизу), может, помогут!

Comment: Спасибо! Может, как-нибудь потом... На самом деле какая разница, главное чтобы inna было с двумя "n", а все остальное не так уж важно :)))

Comment: @__inna__, А как у Вас настроены уведомления о вопросах/ответах/комментах? При обращение через @ник можно настроить уведомление по майлу даже в тех вопросах, по которым информация вам не приходит.  

Кстати, неизвестно, как воспринимает Ваш ник система. Может, и "видит" подчеркивания. Впрочем, вряд ли. Ник не подсвечивается синим, как, например, этот: @DocentI

Comment: Галочка стоит возле "Уведомить меня, когда кто-либо отвечает на мой комментарий, используя обращение @username". Но в почту такие уведомления не приходят, что кто-то обратился по нику.

Comment: А что же тогда значит "уведомить"? К Вам не приходят, потому что невозможно обратиться по нику.

Comment: До меня дошло, почему ник без подчеркиваний! Подчеркивания с двух сторон - это средство форматирования: выделение жирным шрифтом. Ну конечно, как это я сразу не догадалась! Угораздило же такое придумать :)) Написала на "Мета", посмотрим, что скажут.

Comment: Максимум - посоветуют ник сменить. Движок им не переделать, даже если захотят.

Вообще я корю себя, что не объяснил ситуацию внятно, до меня-то она сразу дошла, думал и все понимают, меньше бы было напрасных ожидпний.

Comment: @behemothus, а что означает термин "движок" в этом контексте? Здесь его употребляют, а я не понимаю...

Answer (score 3):

Тавтология, согласен. Масло масляное. Но в отличие от масла и осетрины свежесть новости - понятие относительное, а не качественное, поэтому в определенных контекстах, особенно в эмоциональной речи, вполне допустимо.

Comment: Нет, моя техника при моих привычках делать пять дел одновременно интерактивной проверки просто бы не выдержала.   
Я стараюсь проверять после отправки. 
Спасибо.

Comment: Ничего! Это Ваш стиль...))

Comment: Пришлось сюда перепрыгнуть. Ну вот, теперь я просто @inna, без всяких подчеркиваний :) @behemothus, а корить себя вовсе не нужно, иногда полезно самому додуматься. Как говорится, лучше поздно... Тем более это не вопрос жизни и смерти :)

Comment: @inna, рады за Вас! Теперь бы не перепутать двух Инн: кириллицей и латиницей. Смотрю, и репутация вся при Вас!  

Я и сама подумывала сменить ник, получился наспех и какой-то дурацкий, с претензией. Но, наверное, не найдется достаточно оснований... )))) Побуду уж так.

Comment: Спасибо, @DocentI! Если надумаете, то теперь это стало возможным и на "Русском языке". Раньше можно было только на некоторых форумах, как сказали на "Мета", но по моему запросу разрешили и здесь редактировать ник.

Comment: Да, я туда тоже заглядываю. Боюсь только потеряться..., На  "математике"-то это мне не грозит, там я лидер...  
А вот на "Кодах" постеснялась называться Доцентом. Там я неофит... )))

Comment: @inna, попробовала поменять ник - и не могу придумать приличный. По имени? Оно распространенное, ничего не говорящее. Видимо, моя сущность уже полностью свелась к моему доцентству (((

Comment: Неофит - остроумно :) Да, ник - это дело тонкое, если ставить задачу передать сущность, какую-то черту, при этом чтоб не перегнуть палку, чтоб получилось мило и не нелепо. Я, правда, не заморачивалась, использовала свое имя. Просто к нику привыкаешь сам, привыкают и форумчане, поэтому я резко не меняла его. Если честно, я привыкла, что Вы - @DocentI :) Но это дело хозяйское, главное, чтоб Вам самой было комфортно.

Answer (score 0):

Да, это тавтология. Но не любая тавтология недопустима. Ее можно считать художественным приемом. Здесь, например, происходит усиление смысла.